# How to pass utm_source in a Facebook post?

Tags: android, facebook, utm-tracking

I'm posting a link to my Android app on Facebook (in related community), and I would like to track its performance. So I add "&utm_source=110" in the end of the link. But it seems Facebook deleted this parameter somehow, and added certain "fbclid" instead. But I need my "utm_source" parameter in the link!

How can I fix it?

My link which I post to Facebook community: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.ydns.chernish2.python_free&utm_source=110

Link actually displayed in FB post: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.ydns.chernish2.python_free&fbclid=IwAR34J5FbClzG7SzuvXPBm3fyuV81J9dI6GOW3pskfiiaRFCqAaHTxR1Cd3w

Comment: Not sure you can do that, because it looks like Facebook goes by the `og:url` value to determine the "real" URL.

Comment: OK but can I check incoming URLs with fbclid then somehow? Can't find such an option in Play Console.